# JQuery to add incremental number to div with preceding 0

Tags: jquery

I have a number of CMS generated items that I could like to count and display the item's number in a `div`

I'm using this so far:

```
$('.course-number').each((i, e) => $(e).text(i+1));
```

This correctly outputs 1, 2, 3, 4 etc into the `div.course-number` as expected.

But for aesthetic reasons I would like **numbers below 10 to have a preceding zero** – so the output was 01, 02, 03, 04 etc then 10, 11, 12 etc without a preceding zero.

Can anybody help me achieve this?

(**update:** the proposed [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros) does not provide a complete answer that addresses each need: (1) count each element (2) output the number as text inside the element (3) add a preceding zero IF less than 10)

Comment: Did this solve your problem: `$(e).text((i <= 10?'0':'')(i+1).toString())`

Comment: You can always use `('00' + courseNumber).substr(-2)`.

Comment: @connexo: will not work past 99...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Well you gotta decide how many numbers you want. 01, or 001, or 0001... Of course you can easily modify: `('00' + courseNumber).substr(Math.max(courseNumber.toString().length, 2)*(-1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `i+1` is less than 10, just add the zero...

Within the `.text()` parenthesis, a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator is used. The structure is:

(condition) ? true : false

Where you specify a condition... And a value for `true` and for `false`.
;)

```js
$('.course-number').each((i, e) => $(e).text( ((i+1)<10) ? "0"+(i+1) : i+1  ));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="course-number"></div>
<div class="course-number"></div>
<div class="course-number"></div>
<div class="course-number"></div>
<div class="course-number"></div>
<div class="course-number"></div>
<div class="course-number"></div>
<div class="course-number"></div>
<div class="course-number"></div>
<div class="course-number"></div>
<div class="course-number"></div>
<div class="course-number"></div>
```

Comment: This works great. Also very helpful information about the ternary operator, thank-you!

Answer (score 1):

```js
const fill = function(courseNumber) { return ('0' + courseNumber).substr(Math.max(courseNumber.toString().length, 2)*(-1)) }

console.log(fill(0))

console.log(fill(2))

console.log(fill(10))

console.log(fill(623))

console.log(fill(199999))
```

is another simple solution.

Comment: Wow Connexo! You got angry about that issue right! That's an alternative... But a bit more complicated. +1 anyway, since that works! ;)